# Showing a checkbox button as selected when value in form is set to true

Tags: angular, class, button, angular-forms

I have a form that has a set of checkboxes which are styled as buttons and thus don't stay checked when they are clicked.

I use the Angular template driven approach to forms and use a `*ngFor` loop to set a number of weekdays which can be checked (multiple checkboxes can be checked at the same time if that's unclear).

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" *ngFor="let wday of wdays" [class.active]="f.value.wday">
    <input type="checkbox" [name]="wday" [id]="wday" ngModel [value]="wday">{{ wday }}
  </label>
</div>
```

The form is initiated like this: `<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">` and thus `f.wday` returns `true` (if clicked), `false` if (it was unchecked after being clicked at least once) or `""` (after it was initiated) in the console.

I am a bit confused why the buttons are not visually shown as being active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo (?) instead of:

```
[class.active]="f.value.wday"
```

it needs to be

```
[class.active]="f.value[wday]"
```

so that it will actually point to your form controls. Since as you have it now, it points to a non existing form control named `wday`.

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/SSeqPHFyCQ1JUTLtGouv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to look at [name]="wday"
if all inputs have the same id they will all have the state of the last iteration of "let wday of wdays"

I have had to do this before

```
let wday of wdays; let i = index

[name]="'wday' + i"
```

You probably dont want Id to be the same on all inputs either.

Also what format is wday is it just true false, or is it an object?
I would guess it something like this, and would explain additional issues

```
{  Name: "monday", value: "true" }
```

Comment: The problem wasn't the name of the html tags. It would be weird to iterate through an array that has the name values for each key/index.